# Angularjs - get body element inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to get `body` element in angular directive?  my objective is to do what one do with jquery `$('body').innerWidth();` inside directive. I do not want to use jquery but angular built-in jqlite implementation.

Comment: I wanted to get access to the body tag to change the class - but Angular has bindings that should be used - its just that for me the scope is not there from my buried directive (a modal box) this modal has a class to insert in the body tag which you can understand how that helps.
I prefer to use a binding from logic in my directive..but from the directive how can I access the right scope ? That I comment here is not an answer but some ideas around this problem.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you need to access the body element from within a directive that is applied on another element, you can make use of the [$document](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$document) service like so..

```
app.directive("myDirective", function($document) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    var bodyWidth = $document[0].body.clientWidth;
    console.log("width of body is "+ bodyWidth);
  };
});

<button my-directive>Sample Button</button>
```

You could also use the DOM traversal methods provided in jqLite (though they are much less powerful than what jQuery offers).  For example, you could do a recursive lookup using the `angular.element.parent()` method to find the body tag.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. My directive is deep inside body tag. Is it possible to access body, which may way above the tree (not a child of element)

Comment: so, in your example, is it possible to get width of body inside where you applied the dir on TABLE

Comment: thanks I accepted. If you don't mind, can you show how to get the size  of a div (with id #container), from a child element. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: well, based on the discussion below, it looks like it is not possible. thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: Are you avoiding the use of jQuery for bandwidth reasons?  If you don't need to support older versions of IE, you could use the zepto.js library (which is much smaller file size and supports the full jQuery API).

http://zeptojs.com/

Answer (score 11):

One more variation using the `find()` implementation which is included in angular's jQLite:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {

    var body = angular.element(document).find('body');
    console.log(body[0].offsetWidth);

    };
});
```

Comment: If you look at the angular code under `$SnifferProvider` you'll see a reference to `document.body`, with `document` simply being `document = $document[0] || {}`